# Is it possible to view multiple Chrome devtools panels at once?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to view multiple Chrome devtools panels at the same time?  A split window, like this mockup, would be nice:

[image: mockup of split-window devtools panels]

Or in separate windows.

It would be extremely useful to be able to view the Sources panel and Network panel at the same time, to see exactly when network requests are fired while stepping through code.

The console can be pulled up while inside any other panel by clicking [image: console button] or pressing `esc`, so why not the other panels?

I haven't found much by searching, but maybe this is possible with a [devtools extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html).

Does this exist already?  If not, is it possible?

Comment: Can you raise a bug on http://crbug.com/ and let me know the issue ID

Comment: @Kinlan this isn't a bug, more of a feature request.  It may already be implemented by a devtools extension that I haven't found yet.  I tried posting it at crbug.com but the issue form is *very* geared towards bugs, not feature requests.

Comment: It hasn't been implemented as a devtools extension.  File it as a bug is ok.  A lot of feature requests are done this way.

Comment: @Kinlan I'm searching for the same feature but no luck so far. I checked devtools extension and it doesn't seem possible.The only ugly solution that I found is to open 2 tabs with the same url and open their 2 devtools, one with one panel selected and the other with another panel.

Comment: I have opened a feature request: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=517775

Comment: Just to update, the feature request was closed as too low impact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find this limitation frustrating too, all those other monitors are wasted! Here is poor man's solution:

- launch your chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=9999` command line parameter
- right click on your page to debug and select 'Inspect Element' - this is your debug window #1
- open a separate chrome window and navigate to `chrome://inspect`
- click 'Configure...' and add `localhost:9999`
- within a couple of seconds under 'Remote Targets' you should see tabs you can inspect from your other chrome instance
- click on the tab, and now this is your debug window #2

[image: separate windows chrome developer panels]

Unrelated tip: system wide nightmode experience: http://danielsokolowski.blogspot.com/2018/11/windows-10-8-7-night-mode.html

Comment: Thanks, six years later and I think this is the best we're going to get!

Answer (score 4):

As of Chrome Canary 33.0.1732.0, there's a "Show editor in Drawer" experiment. The editor shows up whenever you hit any anchor to the source code in DevTools.
[image: Editor in drawer experiment]