# Can I use dev tools persist with live site?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, web-development-server

Trying to use [Dev Tools Persist](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow). Had a lot of trouble adding folder but eventually that worked. Folder is faded out and I can't "Map to File System Resource" (right click only shows this:

[image: right click of folders added]

I tried using the "show editor in console" experiment ([here](https://plus.google.com/+DavidGilbertson/posts/HkdGghsp9Hz) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225299/is-it-possible-to-view-multiple-chrome-devtools-panels-at-once)) as a workaround but could never find it, despite enabling experiments.

I'm using dev off the live site. I don't control the site so don't have access to local files. I only need to update styles.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, missing "Map to File System Resource". When my source maps included sourcesContent, the file mappings were automatically made and I could live edit my scss. Apparently chrome uses the content to find the right file.

node-sass --source-map-contents