# Chrome Devtools Workspace 2.0 loses syncing with CSS files after reload

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have added the local folder into the "Filesystem" tab of the Workspace. I see the CSS file I need to edit with the green badge (the linked icon) as shown on the screenshot below. As I make the changes, I see them being reflected on the page. However, as soon as I refresh the page, the linking just disappear just for the file I have edited. But as soon as I upload the file to the server, then the linking starts working until another refresh.

Am I missing something? Is there a setting that I need to do?

[image: Screenshow showing the files being synced]

Comment: Sounds like a bug. See if it's reported on https://crbug.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome was not able to store persistent changes on version 63. They have introduced something called overrides with version 64.

Comment: Can you elaborate, I find that my green sync turns off and I need to reload Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this frustrating thing out as an annoying side effect is that once you loose the mapping breakpoints stop working and the only solution was to reloading Chrome.

It appears sync is lost when using multiple Chrome DevTools trick as per here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55507080/913223 .

The work around is to re-open the file using CTRL+P command palette. **Notice** in the screenshot below the file is duplicated, opening the virtual one re-connects mapping and brings back the green icon.

[image: fix lost Chrome DevTools green icon sync]